# Sitecore 9.1 Update 1 Installation Error

Tags: sitecore-client, xconnect

I am trying to install Sitecore 9.1 update 1 on my local window 10 Machine, 
But I am getting the below error during the PowerShell installation:

```
Install-SitecoreConfiguration : Unable to parse [ResolveCertificatePath(variable('XConnectSolr_Security.XConnect.CertificatePath'))] - 
Exception calling "Evaluate" with "2" argument(s): "The running command stopped because the preference variable "ErrorActionPreference" 
or common parameter is set to Stop: 
Unable to parse [joinpath(variable('XConnectSolr_Security.CertificateStore'), 
variable('XConnectSolr_Security.XConnect.CertificateThumbprint'))] - Exception calling "Evaluate" with "2" argument(s): "The running 
command stopped because the preference variable "ErrorActionPreference" or common parameter is set to Stop: 
Unable to parse 
[GetCertificateThumbprint(parameter('XConnectSolr_XConnectCert'), variable('XConnectSolr_Security.CertificateStore'))] - Exception 
calling "InvokeWithContext" with "2" argument(s): "Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Id' because it is an empty string."""
At C:\Ashish\Sitecore\Software\Sitecore911\Install_new_instance.ps1:77 char:1
+ Install-SitecoreConfiguration @singleDeveloperParams *>&1 | Tee-Objec ...
```

Comment: which SIF version are you using?

Comment: 2.1.0 which is required for Sitecore 9.1 update 1

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are using the right SIF version, which in this case is 2.0.0.

The following command will show you your current version:

```
Get-Command -Module SitecoreInstallFramework | Select-Object -Property name, version
```

If you are still using **SIF 1.2.1** you just need to upgrade it using the following commands:

## To list all installed SIF versions

```
Get-InstalledModule -Name SitecoreInstallFramework -AllVersions
```

## If you already have SIF 2.0.0 installed, you just need to set it as the current used version

```
Remove-Module -Name SitecoreInstallFramework
Import-Module -Name SitecoreInstallFramework -RequiredVersion 2.0.0
```

## If you don't have SIF 2.0.0, then you must install it

```
Install-Module -Name SitecoreInstallFramework -RequiredVersion 2.0.0
```